# How to convert console python args to dict using json.loads?

Tags: python, json, selenium, cmd

I have 2 files: crawler.py and runner.py

And simple dictionary like:

```
action_dict={'create 
user':3.0,'edit 
user':5.0,'delete user':2.0}
```

I want to send action_dict as an argument from runner to crawler.py through the windows cmd.
I've tried to use Json.dump.
Something like this(in runner.py):

```
arg_to_cmd = 
json.dumps(action_dict)
cmd = 'python crawler.py ' + arg_to_cmd
```

Then in crawler.py I tried to get it:

```
args=sys.argv[1:]
if args:
 diet_from_runner=json.dumps.loads(args[0])
```

Also I tried to parse it without dump. I send string like:

```
str_action_dict='{"create 
user":3.0,"edit 
user":5.0,"delete user":2.0}'
```

Also I tried to modify string from args and the best thing that I could get is a string from json.loads. So, how to get dictionary with json?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **literal_eval** to convert string representation(console python args) of dictionary into python objects as:

```
import ast
js = "{'create user':3.0,'edit user':5.0,'delete user':2.0}"
out=ast.literal_eval(js)
print(out)
# {'create user': 3.0, 'edit user': 5.0, 'delete user': 2.0}
```

Comment: Still get the error of parsing through literal eval. I suppose it works great in script but not good if I get string straight from the console args.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `json.loads()` on the input parameters:

```
import sys
import json

params = sys.argv[1:]
assert(type(json.loads(params[0])) == dict)
```